# Magento2.5 Related Products image url path incorrect after moving website

Tags: magento-2.2.5, related-products

I recently moved a Magento 2.5 based website to a new server and now on the product detail page the related products the product images are not loading. Upon inspecting the image tag I see the url is missing a /

So for example the image tag is

```
<img src="https://*****.com/pub/media/catalog/productb/i/abcnails.jpg" class="img-resposive">
```

However the correct url for the image is

```
img src="https://****.com/pub/media/catalog/product/b/i/bipc080nails.jpg" class="img-resposive">
```

So I am wondering how I could fi this? Not sure what database table stores this information or if there is somewhere else to fix this?

Comment: Check base url  parameters in backoffice, it seems your media url is missing the ending /

Comment: I checked the base url and base link url and both have trailing slashes. however I dont have any value at all entered in the Base URL for User Media Files text

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed you meant only related products. I thought you meant all products. You'd check the template where related products are printed (any 3rd party module?)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?